# Is it possible to redirect or to get live video data from a website?

Tags: video, https

If I am at a website where I can cam with other people, is it possible to get the video/stream/traffic data and redirect that information to another server/source? It is HTTPS and there is my problem of understanding.

HTTPS:

Person A wants to connect to a HTTPS website. That website sends a SSL certificate (public key) to the user. Person A sends a request with the public key from that website and receives an encrypted traffic. With his private key, he can decrypt that traffic.

But when I can see the video stream, the traffic has to be decrypted and it has to be possible to redirect that video stream or am I thinking wrong at some point?

Thanks!